# Exception thrown in a lock c#2

Tags: c#, multithreading, crash

I've a strance behaviour with C#2, an exception is thrown will calling a lock(...). I have the following exception :
System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.
   at System.Threading.Monitor.Enter(Object obj)...

Have you seen that kind of exception ?
TIA

Comment: Yes, I have seen that kind of exception.

Comment: can you please post your code that throwing exception?

Comment: is this an ASP.NET app by any chance?

Comment: Post the stack trace of the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This exception is being thrown because your thread is being aborted.

Threads can be aborted in one of several situations: another thread calls [`Thread.Abort`](http://msmvps.com/blogs/peterritchie/archive/2007/08/22/thead-abort-is-a-sign-of-a-poorly-designed-program.aspx), an `AppDomain` is being [unloaded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unload.aspx), or an ASP.NET application is being [recycled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.initiateshutdown.aspx).